# excel: get all rows of data which have dates within 20 working days of todays date and within 5 working days of todays date, and if todays date?

Tags: excel, date

I have a sheet (sheet2) of data like so:

```
A       B        C       D              
Cat     kilo     1      19/10/2015               
Dog     unit     8      12/11/2015
Pig     cm       6      30/10/2015
Cow     meter    1      05/11/2015
```

and on sheet 1 I want to list all my rows which have dates approaching either within 20 working days of todays date, within 5 working days and if the date is today's date. ideally these should be listed nearest date to furthest date, i.e.

```
Cat     kilo     1      19/10/2015 
Cow     meter    1      30/10/2015
Pig     cm       6      05/11/2015
```

I do not know how I would be able to do this, please can someone show me how to get started. thanks in advance

Where my trail of thought has got me so far:

```
=IF((D:D<=5),INDEX(MATCH...
```

Comment: Just for clarification... you have three conditions regarding the dates. It seems like conditions #2 and #3 are already included in the definition of #1... ?

Comment: @ExcelHero thanks my examples shouldn't be taken too literal, I can see what you mean that conditions 2 and 3 are included in condition 1 but I still need all 3 conditions, see updated question for clarity thanks

Comment: Add a formula in ColE to calculate difference between the current date and ColD, then sort on that...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Don't just abandon questions you ask if you figure it out!  submit your own answer or accept someone elses.

Answer (score 0):

I used a mixture of index/match, rank, and the now function to accomplish this as well as two columns which you can hide.  This formula ranks the date closest to todays date as number 1 and includes any dates that are 20 days in the past or 20 days in the future.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

The formula in F2 is

```
=IF(E2="","",RANK(E2, $E$2:$E$5))
```

The formula in cell A8 (the one you will put on a separate sheet) is

```
=INDEX(A2:F5,MATCH(1, F2:F5, 0 ),1)
```

The formula for cells B8 - D8 are just vlookups based off of the value in A8.
B8 Formula =

```
=VLOOKUP(A8, A2:F5, 2, FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: You can use the today() function instead of now.  now() includes hours and minutes which you don't need.